# Ruby on rails upload button with empty file field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and would like to have a question answered:

I have an upload csv field on my form which works perfectly fine when I actually upload a file. But when I hit the upload button without attaching a file, I get an exception: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass. Is there a way to stay on the same page and instead show a "no file uploaded" warning?

I've tried doing `if(params[:model][:file].nil?) redirect_to model_path end` but it continues to the rest of the code. Thanks in advance for the help.

Views Code:

```
<%= form_for (@model), :url=>{ :controller=>"models", :action => 'create'}, :html=>{:multipart => true} do |f| %>           
    <p><%= f.label :file, 'Import csv file' %><br/>
      <%= f.file_field :file, :accept => "text/csv"%></p>
      <%= submit_tag "Upload" %>
  <% end %>

Controller Code:

        def create
   51     @model = Model.new
   52     
   53     @model.date_created = Time.now.utc
   54     
   55   
   56     #handles csv input    
   59     if(params[:model][:file])
   60       
   61       @model.id = SecureRandom.uuid; 
   62       file_data = params[:model][:file].read
   63       @parsed_file  = CSV.parse(file_data)
   64       n=0
   65       @parsed_file.each do |row|
   74   
   75         if @model.save
   76           n=n+1
   77         end 
   79       end

   81     else
   82       @model.id = "different type"
   83     end
   84 
   85       respond_to do |format|
   86         if @model.save
   87           if(params[:model][:file] )
   88             format.html { redirect_to @model, :notice => "Successfully imported the CSV file. #{n} new records added to the database" }
   89           else
   90             format.html { redirect_to @model, notice: 'Model entry was successfully created.' }
   91           end
   92           format.json { render json: @model, status: :created, location: @model }
   93         else
   94           format.html { render action: "new" }
   95           format.json { render json: @model.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
   96         end
```

Comment: You need to show some code for anyone to help you. Further to this the method that you are calling must be empty which is why you are getting this error

Answer (score 1):

try in controller...

```
 if params[:model][:file].blank?
      flash[:error] = 'Fields cannot be blank.'
      redirect_to model_path
  end
```

Second thing.. i wont recommend u to use 'model' as a controller bcoz it is rails keyword. Use another name.

Comment: Thanks for the reseponse, it works when I just call params[:file] instead of params[:model][:file], which still gives the nil error. Any idea why this happens though?

Answer (score 0):

You should use Jquery validation.

**For example :**

```
<form name="myform" id="myform" action="#" method="post">
<input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile"  />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

then you can validate the file input field when it is changed using the following code...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#myform").submit({
        var file_value = $('#myfile').val();
        if ( file_value.length =< 0 ){
            alert('No such file exist');
        }
    });
});
```

With in the same function, you can validate the format of file as well.

```
var ext = $('#myfile').val().match(/\.(.+)$/)[1];
    switch (ext) {
        case 'csv', 'CSV':
           alert('CSV File- Correct File');
            break;
        default:
            alert('This is not an allowed file type.');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To check if a file is attached for upload or not, you can simply check if a file exits in params with

`if params[:file]`

If you want to check for the extension of the file, you can with

`File.extname(params[:file].path) == '.csv'`

better way is to check for the content-type of the file and respond appropriately depending on the content-type you can do this with

`params[:file].content_type == 'text/csv'`